# Converting PHP Curl queries to Python requests

Tags: php, python, curl, python-requests

I've been facing a few problems trying to convert the following PHP curl queries to Python requests.

#### Given PHP Code

```
$cfile = new CURLFile($filePath,$fileType,$filename);
$request='{"signers":["abc@xyz.com"],"expire_in_days":10, "display_on_page":"all"}';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('authorization: Basic Base64encode(client_id:client_secret)'));
$post = array('file'=>$cfile,'request' =>$request);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
$res = curl_exec($ch)
```

#### My version of Python code

```
request_data = {}
request_data['signers'] = ['abc@xyz.com']
request_data['expire_in_days'] = 10
request_data['display_on_page'] = 'all'
temp_file_path = 'PdfTest.pdf'
files = {'file': open(temp_file_path, 'rb')}
headers = {}
headers['content-type'] = "multipart/form-data"
headers['authorization'] = 'Basic '+auth # auth contains b64 client:secret
r = requests.post(url, files=files, data={'request': request_data}, headers=headers)
```

Considering my request URLs are the same and so is the base 64 value for authorization. The PHP code returns the right response from the server but the Python one strangely says provides a response telling `"code":"UNSUPPORTED_MEDIA_TYPE"`

Comment: Why did you choose to set 'content-type' to `multipart/form-data`?

Comment: The API documentation mentions to use that content-type while sending the data to the API. Even without that, the error I receive is still the same.

Comment: did you try to choose files that aren't PDF? seems like it's the problem

Comment: Yup, I also sent TXT files with the same error. Ideally the aim is to send PDF files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more checks, I seemed to figure out the issue was with the following lines, `files` needs mandatory `filetype` which can be obtained from `MimeTypes().guess_type(path)[0]` and the `request_data` should have been `json.dumps(request_data)`

```
files = {'file': (temp_file_path, open(temp_file_path, 'rb'), filetype)}
# .... Other code
r = requests.post(url, files=files, data={'request': json.dumps(request_data)}, headers=headers)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $url_0 = 'https://pranatrader.ir/services/LoginUser';
    $post_filed = 'username=0061625671&password=db00d9250ef8a9243e6d9bc1e960f09d1aaf517a&preferredClientID=Mobile&ip=undefined';

    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "$url_0");

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_filed);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'cache-control: no-cache',
        'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Content-Length: 107',
        'Host: pranatrader.ir',
        'Connection: Keep-Alive',
        'User-Agent: okhttp/3.12.1'
    ));

    $server_output = curl_exec($ch);

    #echo '<xmp>' . print_r($server_output, true) . '</xmp>';

    $header_size = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE);
    $header = substr($server_output, 0, $header_size);
    $body = substr($server_output, $header_size);


    $json_result = json_decode($body);

    echo '<xmp>' . print_r($json_result, true) . '</xmp>';

    curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Hi, can you maybe describe, what you did in your code?